# Formula for the length of line that connects two sides of a triangle.

Tags: triangles

For the triangle in the picture, coordinates of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are known. Is there an explicit formula for length $XY$, as a function of height $h$? It's a function of other variables as well, but it's important that it depends explicitly on $h$.[image]

$XY$ is parallel to side $c$, but I'm not good at drawing.

Comment: Yes, try doing it for a right angled triangle first, and remember the length of the base is $\|A-B\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Cxy$ is similar to $CAB$, so the sides are in the same ratio as the altitudes.